# How to deploy Libgdx game into the real web server

Tags: html, deployment, libgdx

I built the Libgdx game with Gradle and success in deployment on localhost. So I move the code into the real server. However, when I open the browser of my game..it seems like the browser reads url (localhost). Nothing appear!!  I am wondering if I have to set up more info for javascript to run the game on the real server or in config files somewhere ?

Comment: how you access your web server, there must be an address. Access in this way https://address/gamename  , if you kept at root public folder

Answer (score 0):

How you build web-server version of your project? You should use this command:

```
$ ./gradlew html:dist
```

Results files will be inside folder: `html/build/dist`

You should copy all files to webroot folder of your vhost. 
Structure should be something like this:

- `assets`
- `html`
- index.html
- soundmanager2-jsmin.js
- soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js * - i also download from soundmanager website nodebug version of soundmanager
- soundmanager2-setup.js
- styles.css

I was programming gwt project  few times. For example: http://ciufcia.pl/boomki-nimm2.

If this does not help, please give some logs from webconsole.

Comment: I compiled with gradlew using the command you mentioned.  I used GWT version. 2.8.

Comment: I compiled with gradlew using the command you mentioned.  I used GWT version. 2.8. It works in localhost. I moved codes to the server with all files you mentioned. I access my game at [link](http://www.gigifuntolearn.com/RobotClever/)  ..the browser asked me to recompile..and an error from GWT..   Let's see. Thanks.

Comment: I see. It works in IE but not in Firefox!! May have to check browser compatible. Many thanks to all.